Media3 Mp4Muxer and FragmentedMp4Muxer throwing IllegalStateException
I'm migrating from MediaMuxer to media3.FragmentedMP4Muxer/media3.MP4Muxer to take advantage of fragmented Mp4 files to avoid file corruptions if recording is interrupted. I'm encountering an IllegalStateException when I use either Mp4Muxer or FragmentedMP4Muxer to mux a video with two tracks - one video from the camera, one audio from the mic.
The exception occurs randomly, but normally within the first 60 seconds of recording. For example, if I record a short video (say 10 seconds) before the IllegalStateException is thrown, the video records fine and can be played back.  But eventually after between 30 - 60 seconds, an IllegalStateException is thrown due to the following assertion failing:
MP4Writer.java (if using MP4Muxer):
...
private void flushPending(Track track) throws IOException {
    checkState(track.pendingSamplesByteBuffer.size() == track.pendingSamplesBufferInfo.size()); //<< triggered here
...

FragmentedMP4Writer.java (if using FragmentedMP4Muxer):
...
private ProcessedTrackInfo processTrack(int trackId, Track track) {
    checkState(track.pendingSamplesByteBuffer.size() == track.pendingSamplesBufferInfo.size()); //<< triggered here
...

It's not immediately clear to me why the sizes between pendingSamplesbyteBuffer and pendingSamplesBufferInfo  would ever differ and therefore why the IllegalStateException would ever be thrown. There are no comments or documentation that explains why this would occur and how to avoid it.
Example Stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException at androidx.media3.common.util.Assertions.checkState(Assertions.java:85)
at androidx.media3.muxer.FragmentedMp4Writer.processTrack(FragmentedMp4Writer.java:296)
at androidx.media3.muxer.FragmentedMp4Writer.processAllTracks(FragmentedMp4Writer.java:289)
at androidx.media3.muxer.FragmentedMp4Writer.createFragment(FragmentedMp4Writer.java:239)
at androidx.media3.muxer.FragmentedMp4Writer.writeSampleData(FragmentedMp4Writer.java:126)
at androidx.media3.muxer.FragmentedMp4Muxer.writeSampleData(FragmentedMp4Muxer.java:185)
at xx.xx.encoder.VideoEncoderCore.drainVideoEncoder(VideoEncoderCore.java:374)
at xx.xx.TextureMovieEncoder.handleFrameAvailable(TextureMovieEncoder.java:1401)


It might help to debug if you print both sizes in the error message.

@dev.bmax do you mean both stack traces?

I mean to print buffer.remaining() and bufferInfo.size in the error message that you throw.

@dev.bmax The Mp4Muxer and the sub classes are Android classes that can't be extended and is read only. I can't access those variables from outside the class either.

Sorry, If you can compare 2 numbers in checkState why can't you print them?

They're private, in a private Android class that can't be extended. I can't print them (at least not at the point in the code where it's crashing) because I can't modify the file, and I can't access the variables from outside the class. In any case, based on feedback from the Media3 team it seems this is caused by a threading issue between muxing of audio and video, so I'll be looking into how my app is managing the thread as a likely cause.
